# Cubature Kalman Filter vs. Kalman Filter

Tags: estimation, kalman-filter, state-space-models

In the context of time series forecasting, does CKF perform better over KF or other Time Series models?

Comment: This would depend on what *model* you are using -  for a linear-Gaussian state-space model CKF and KF would produce the same results while for any other model the vanilla KF is not applicable.

Comment: My understanding on this subject is limited. I'm referring to the paper published in IEEE where CKF is defined as a new nonlinear filter for high-dimensional state estimation. Literature suggests that for solving non-linear dynamic system Bayesian filters are ideal. But Bayesian filters possess challenges with computation and hence several approximations have been implemented, CKF being one of them. My question is whether one has experimented with CKF in time series forecasting problems? If yes, has one seen if it performs better than KF and/or other Time Series models?

Comment: CKF is not "a time series model" so this still seems somewhat unclear (does any use of CKF count? What separates a "time series" from some other sequence of observations?) Also, "have you observed" sounds like an opinion poll which is not suitable for here

Comment: I've edited the question based on your inputs. CKF is not a "a time series model" but it can be used for time series forecasting. I think you've misinterpreted the question

Comment: Do you have a specific model in mind that would be used? Otherwise you cannot just "use CKF." To elaborate, I think there are two issues here: 1. would a non-linear state-space model perform better than a linear one 2. would CKF perform well for approximately filtering said non-linear model. It's unclear what your ideas for (1) are.  I guess the "is there any use of CKF for time-series forecasts that performs better than any use of KF" is technically clear but this simply feels to me a strange question (maybe too broad)